# Use std::vector::iterator to alter values stored in std::vector?

Tags: c++, iterator, selection-sort

I'm new to C++, and am trying to implement the Selection Sort Algorithm as an exercise.

I've gotten as far as trying to swap the value in the left-most memory location with the value in the memory location of the minimum of the unsorted portion of the vector.

( See the code below. )

Is it possible to use `std::vector::iterator`'s to alter the values contained in the vector it belongs to?

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, vector<T> thisVector ) {

  for( size_t i = 0, choke = thisVector.size(); i < choke; i++ )
    out << thisVector[ i ] << " ";

  return out;
}

template<typename T>
typename vector<T>::iterator get_minimum( vector<T>& thisVector, typename vector<T>::iterator pos, typename vector<T>::iterator end ) {

  T min = *pos;
  typename vector<T>::iterator minPos;

  while ( pos != end ) {
    if ( *pos < min ) {
      min = *pos;
      minPos = pos;
    }
    pos++;
  }
  return minPos;
}

template<typename T>
void swap( typename vector<T>::iterator pos, typename vector<T>::iterator& minPos ) {

  T temp = *pos;

  // I was hoping the following two lines would modify the vector passed to selection_sort
  pos = *minPos;
  minPos = temp;
  return;
}

template<typename T>
void selection_sort( vector<T>& thisVector, typename vector<T>::iterator pos ) {

  typename vector<T>::iterator end = thisVector.end();
  typename vector<T>::iterator minPos = get_minimum( thisVector, pos, end );
  cout << "Swap was given this " << *pos << " " << *minPos << endl;
  swap( pos, minPos );
  cout << "and returned this " << *pos << " " << *minPos << endl;
  return;
}

int main() {

  // initialize random seed
  srand (time(NULL));

  // Create data stub
  vector<int> myThing;
  do {
    myThing.push_back( rand() % 20 );
  } while ( myThing.size() <= 10 );

  cout << "Unsorted: " << myThing << endl;
  selection_sort( myThing, myThing.begin() );
  cout << "  Sorted: " << myThing << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can check that very easily in a small program. The code you have posted is extraneous to the core question.

Comment: @RSahu - Except the core question is--how can I do this in the context of my approach to `selection_sort`.

Comment: Your `swap` function is whack.. you mean `T temp = *pos; *pos = *minPos; *minPos = temp;`. There is already a standard function for this BTW, `std::swap(*pos, *minPos)`.  `minPos` does not need to be passed by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are facing with swapping the values the iterators point to is caused by the fact that the compiler picks up `std::swap` by using ADL. `std::swap` just swaps where the iterators point to but not the values the iterators point to.

If you name the function `myswap` and call `myswap` instead of `swap`, you are probably going to see compiler error messages. Check out [my question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277546/why-is-template-parameter-deduction-failing-with-stdvectortiterator).

Instead, if you use:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void myswap(Iterator pos1,
            Iterator pos2)
{
   auto temp = *pos1;
   *pos1 = *pos2;
   *pos2 = temp;
}
```

everything should work. Here's a working program, using g++ 4.8.2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<typename Iterator>
void myswap(Iterator pos1, Iterator pos2)
{
   auto temp = *pos1;
   *pos1 = *pos2;
   *pos2 = temp;
}

void testMyswap()
{
   std::cout << "\nTesting myswap()\n";
   std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

   std::vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin();
   std::vector<int>::iterator temp = std::next(iter, 2);

   std::cout << "Values iterators point to before swap.\n";
   std::cout << *iter << " " << *temp << std::endl;
   myswap(iter, temp);
   std::cout << "Values iterators point to after swap.\n";
   std::cout << *iter << " " << *temp << std::endl;

   std::cout << "The vector after the swap.\n";
   for ( iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter )
   {
      std::cout << *iter << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   testMyswap();
   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Testing myswap()
Values iterators point to before swap.
1 3
Values iterators point to after swap.
3 1
The vector after the swap.
3 2 1 4 5 6
```

Comment: I wish I had enough points to upvote you; this answer is spectacular! Thanks!

Comment: @LMiz, I am glad you liked the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  Given an iterator `iter`, `*iter` can be assigned to like a normal lvalue to modify the underlying container, e.g.:

```
*iter = 5;  // The value in the container that `iter` points to is now 5.
```

Comment: Thank you!

In my code, inside the `swap` function, I do just that. I try running the code with both `*myIter` and `myIter`, but am seeing no modification to the container.

I wonder what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. And here is a trick to make your life easier.

[Swap is already a defined function.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Add `#include <utility>` and you get `swap` for free. Many C++ objects define swap specializations. For example, `std::vector` implements a swap between two vectors by simply swapping the pointers.

For your code you can remove your definition of swap and use `swap(*pos, *minPos)`

Comment: Thanks for replying. As stated in the original question, the goal of this exercise is to completely write the algorithm from scratch, and not rely on existing libraries other than those used for storage.

Comment: @LMiz: You didn't write vector. Why write swap?

Comment: " ...not rely on existing libraries other than those used for storage..."

Comment: So how are you planning to display output with that restriction?

Comment: By not behaving like a troll. ;)

Comment: @LMiz: I checked. You said, "As stated in the original question" and that isn't in the original question. The original question was not edited either. No one is a mind reader, you know.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to namesapce my code: being a very new newbie, I hadn't realized `std::swap(iter, iter)` already exists, and was being called--rather than my `swap` function.

Nonetheless, once I namespaced my code, jwodder's response proved to do the trick: by using `*iter` rather than `iter`, my code compiled and the vector was properly modified by `swap`.